# Add extension to Opera Neon

Tags: browser, opera-extension

How do I add extensions (like in Google Chrome) in the new* browser Opera Neon? **Any help would be appreciated.**
*I am not asking about the simple Opera browser. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Opera Neon has lots of new features – and many of the Opera browser features you know and love – there are some key features we have not included, such as our native ad-blocker, VPN and the ability to add **extensions**.

See [here](http://www.opera.com/blogs/desktop/2017/01/opera-neon-concept-browser/)

Comment: by what time will we be getting that feature?

Comment: I do not know about that. But I guess they are doing survey that how many people are interested on it. On the basis of this they will launch a complete or final version. But again this is my thought not official

You should ask this question from their support. They can better deal with it.
@Dragonborn

Comment: @Dragonborn please do mark a tick if you agree with my answer
Thanks

Comment: Is Opera Neon a Chromium-based browser?

Comment: Any updates to this question? I really love the concept of Opera Neon!

Comment: @ConAntonakos not yet. FOr more information see this link -> http://blogs.opera.com/desktop/2017/01/opera-neon-concept-browser/